# Update Object ID of collection

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I have my own collection in mongo db but by default it generated a unique object id ? How can i replace it with my own object id in studio 3T or compass?

I tried manually inserting the object id with JSON doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question, please try to be as specific as you can about your problem and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code [within your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of editing the default ID generated by mongo I suggest you to use a different attribute name as a unique id and leave _id as it is.
You can create a unique index in your collection with this command
`db.collection.createIndex( { "my_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )`

You cannot edit the immutable field autogenerated "_id" but you can set it when inserting the object to the collection (i.e. `db.collection.insert({"_id": ObjectId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")})`).